# Remove amdgpu-pro and get the opensource driver

Tags: 16.04, drivers, radeon, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Cinnamon desktop, Verde = Radeon HD7770 graphic card. Had installed the proprietary driver amdgpu-pro 17.50 after the 17.40 had some stability problems. 17.50 runs OK, except some games simply do not run. F.ex. Factorio has memory leak or something like that, which could be helped on 17.40, but not on 17.50.

So I decided to ditch the proprietary and jump on the opensource driver (is it called radeon?). All the guides say, simply uninstall the amdgpu-pro and you will have the opensource. Nope, not for me. I get black (somewhat) screen, without even CTRL-ALT-F1 possibility. But, the ssh works, I can connect from my phone and do some maintenance as well as from the failsafe boot option.

When I edit the grub2 config to have nomodeset, I can boot into software rendered low resolution desktop with Cinnamon message "Running in software rendering mode": Factorio runs, but slow as hell = CPU is working for the GPU.
I have done the amdgpu-pro-uninstall, which now do not work anymore, as expected. Have purged and reinstalled the xorg and what not.
Funny enough dmesg gives this:

```
[drm:amdgpu_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* VGACON disables amdgpu kernel modesetting.
```

I suppose, I should not have anything to do anymore with amdgpu.
Command lsmod does not show anything amdgpu or radeon. So automatic install of the default is not working?
Another funny observation:

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde XT [Radeon HD 7770/8760 / R7 250X]
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Cape Verde XT [Radeon HD 7770/8760 / R7 250X]
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
```

Shouldn't I just have one? How do I get the proprietary driver off completely and the opensource one on?

Comment: Looks like I have tried too hard and created some obstacle with also trying the padooka repo. As soon as I try to remove any amd related package, which comes from padooka repository, I get only choice to also remove A LOT of packages from normal desktop suite, like Firefox, Cinnamon, etc. Is there a way to not remove these, but remove anything from padooka?

Comment: You can try the ppa-purge utility. This tool is clever enough to not only remove the packages from a certain ppa but also downgrade them with existing packages from the official Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded the daily build for the yet to be released ubuntu 18.04 and my RX 560 works without installing amdgpu-pro. I could not find any way to get it to work with 16.04.